# Why is the lazy pattern match version of splitAt function faster?

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

The `splitAt` function can be implemented as following (https://wiki.haskell.org/Lazy_pattern_match):

```
import Prelude hiding (splitAt)
splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
splitAt n xs =
  if n<=0
     then ([], xs)
     else
        case xs of
          [] -> ([], [])
          y:ys ->
            case splitAt (n-1) ys of
              ~(prefix, suffix) -> (y : prefix, suffix) -- Here using lazy pattern match

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let r = splitAt 1000000 $ repeat 'a'
  print $ length $ fst r
```

And using the strict pattern match can slow the speed very much.

```
time ./lazy     -- 0.04s user 0.00s system 90% cpu 0.047 total
time ./strict   -- 0.12s user 0.02s system 96% cpu 0.147 total
```

I cannot get the reason. According to the article, the strict version may need more memory and all recursive calls to check whether the pattern fits. But I think the lazy version also needs all recursive calls and needs memory to contain the result of recursive function calls. What makes that differences?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a bunch of differences.

Let's look into the operational difference between the variants with and without the `~` on line 11.

Evaluation in GHC Haskell is driven by pattern-matching.  When a pattern is matched in a case expression or the LHS of a function definition, it requires that the constructors in the pattern be evaluated.  (Patterns in let and where bindings are treated as lazy pattern matches.)  So that means evaluating `splitAt 1000000 (repeat 'a')` depends on matching the `(,)` constructor resulting from the recursive call to `splitAt 999999 ...`, and so on, all the way down to the final call of `splitAt 0 ...`.  This requires stack space to evaluate.  Quite a lot of it, in fact.  It's very possible the stack has to be grown several times to avoid crashing.

In addition, the entire result string `"aaaaa..."` is built on the heap while this is happening, before `length` ever starts to process it. (Due to optimizations in `repeat`, the second element of the result is actually a circularly linked list which never allocates anything new in the whole recursive evaluation.)

When the pattern match is made lazy, things change.  The return value from `splitAt 1000000 (repeat 'a')` is evaluated to be `('a':_thunk1, _thunk2)` without ever making a recursive call to `splitAt`.  This is a pattern known as guarded corecursion. The further evaluation is hidden behind data constructors like `(,)` and `(:)`, and so only performed if demanded by another case expression.

The call to `fst` throws away `_thunk2`, so it won't ever be evaluated.  The call to `length` starts by consuming the first `(:)` constructor, throwing out the `'a'` value, and then making a recursive call on `_thunk1`.  At this point, nothing in memory is still referring to the `(:)` constructor, so the garbage collector is free to reclaim it when it runs next. (The `'a'` value is shared, so there are still pointers to it, so it neither gets collected nor allocated during this process.)

What happens when `_thunk1` is evaluated is a bit subtle. It makes the recursive call to `splitAt 999999 ...`.  It results in `('a':_thunk3, _thunk4)`.  Nothing is holding on to `_thunk4`, so it's free to be garbage collected whenever.  Evaluation of `length` proceeds as above.  The `(:)` constructor is no longer held in memory, and is free to be collected.

Evaluation proceeds that way, only ever holding on to a single `(:)` constructor on the heap at a time, and without burning any stack space at all.  And GHC's garbage collector's run time depends on the size of the resident set.  As there is at most one `(:)` constructor resident, it goes *really* fast in this case.

I suspect in this case, that's the speed difference you're seeing.  You should try running the two programs with the argument `+RTS -s` and looking at stats regarding maximum resident size and garbage collector run time.

It's possible GHC is being *really* clever in optimization, though.  I haven't checked it out, but I know in some cases it can rewrite algorithms in terms of explicit `(:)` application in terms of the [`build`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#v:build) function. If it were to do so, it would allow foldr/build fusion to remove the allocation of the `(:)` constructors entirely.  (Yes, `length` is defined in terms of `foldr` via some really cool tricks for efficiency, mostly to allow foldr/build fusion to work.)

If that's the case, you'd find even less allocation taking place in the lazy case - but the strict case would be just as bad.  I don't think that's likely to be happening here, but I'm not sure, as I haven't tested.